# why we have to use several nodes in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I'm new to big data and hadoop. got some learning courses and saw this picture:
[image]

It says using a single machine makes progress mush faster [first one]
I can't understand so why we have to involve several node? =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why hadoop supported to operate in three modes has been described in this blog "[Hadoop Modes](https://learnhadoopwithme.wordpress.com/2013/08/16/hadoop-modes-standalone-pseudo-distributed-fully-distributed/)" as simple to understand. 
Here is the secret how **standalone mode** works faster :

> In standalone mode, there are no Hadoop Daemons (NameNode, DataNode,
>   Secondary NameNode, JobTracker & TaskTracker) that are running in the
>   background.
>
> As a result you will,
>
> - Not have NameNode storing meta-data information.
> - Not have a DataNode, as there will be no HDFS. The file will be stored locally on the hard disk.
> - Not have a TaskTracker sending status reports the JobTracker.
> - Not have a JobTracker as there are no TaskTrackers to manage.
>
> As the name suggests, everything in standalone mode runs in a **single
>   JVM** (single machine). It is best suited when you want to test your
>   program for bugs with small input (stored locally). It is also known
>   as the ***LocalJobRunner mode***.

For detailed information, Please read the book O'Reilly's ***Hadoop: A definitive guide*** by *Tom White*.